# Getting undefined "type" error when using createAction from redux-api-middleware library

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, redux-api-middleware

I am trying to use the createAction function but am met with the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this but I am assuming it has to do with middleware but I've tried adding that too and it still wont work.

this is what my store looks like:

```
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { routerMiddleware } from "react-router-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { apiMiddleware } from "redux-api-middleware";
import Immutable from "immutable";

import moduleReducers from "./reducers";
import routerReducer from "./reactRouterReducer";

export default function createStore(history, initialState) {
  const middlewares = [thunk, apiMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];
  const enhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

  const reducer = combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer,
    ...moduleReducers,
  });

  const preLoadedState = Immutable.fromJS(initialState || {});
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
    preLoadedState,
    enhancers,
  });
}
```

this is what my reducer looks like:

```
import { createAction } from "redux-api-middleware";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import deep from "deep-get-set";
import config from "../config/config";

const SET_PROJECT = "SET_PROJECT";
const SET_PROJECTS = "SET_PROJECTS";
const SET_LOADING = "SET_LOADING";
const SET_ERROR = "SET_ERROR";

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  hasError: false,
  user_projects: null,
  project: null,
};

export const fetchProjectsList = () =>
  createAction({
    endpoint: `${config?.apiHost}/projects`,
    method: "GET",
    headers: [],
    credentials: "include",
    types: [SET_LOADING, SET_PROJECTS, SET_ERROR],
  });
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PROJECT: {
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasError: false,
        project: action?.project,
      };
      return newState;
    }
    case SET_PROJECTS: {
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasError: false,
        user_projects: action?.payload,
      };
      return newState;
    }
    case SET_LOADING: {
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        hasError: false,
        project: action?.project,
      };
      return newState;
    }
    case SET_ERROR: {
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        hasError: true,
        project: action?.project,
      };
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I've tried setting up my store in all sorts of ways with different redux versions and still get the same error. It's funny cause I used this exact same function for a class and was able to use it successfully but for some reason I am lost on why this isn't working now. I know for a fact that the createAction function takes an object with a types key. I'm out of options. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a *direct* answer to your question, I have a few suggestions on how you can improve that code.

First, with Redux Toolkit's `configureStore` API you don't have to do all the middleware setup and composing yourself.  Instead, you can do:

```
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
    preLoadedState,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
      getDefaultMiddleware()
        .concat(apiMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history))

  });
```

Second, as a general observation: we specifically recommend *against* using Immutable.js, and instead recommend that you *should* use Immer for immutable updates:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#use-immer-for-writing-immutable-updates
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#use-plain-javascript-objects-for-state

More specifically, Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` API already has Immer built in.  It also automatically generates action creators and action types for you, so you don't have to write any of those yourself:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#writing-slices

And finally, Redux Toolkit includes our "RTK Query" data fetching and caching API, which can eliminate the need for writing *any* actions, thunks, middleware, reducers, or effects for fetching data:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

As an example, all of this file could *probably* be replaced with:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${config?.apiHost ?? ''}`,
    endpoints: (build) => ({
      getProjects: build.query({
        query: () => '/projects'
      })
    })
  })
)}

export const { useGetProjectsQuery } = api;
```

Add the RTK Query API middleware and reducer to the store setup, use the query hook in a component, and *all* the data fetching and caching is done for you automatically!